# "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when connecting to same site in SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl

Ok, for our site, which I will say is "https://www.foo-bar.com", and is a .NET MVC 4.5.1 application, we have the following code:

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.foo-bar.com/category.rss");
var response = http.GetResponse();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
s = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

This works locally, AND it works in production under "http", but as soon as we go to https, we get the following error:

```
{  
   "ClassName":"System.Net.WebException",
   "Message":"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.",
   "Data":null,
   "InnerException":{  
      "ClassName":"System.IO.IOException",
      "Message":"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.",
      "Data":null,
      "InnerException":{  
         "NativeErrorCode":10054,
         "ClassName":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
         "Message":"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host",
         "Data":null,
         "InnerException":null,
         "HelpURL":null,
         "StackTraceString":" at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)\r\n at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)",
         "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
         "RemoteStackIndex":0,
         "ExceptionMethod":"8\nReceive\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.Sockets.Socket\nInt32 Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)",
         "HResult":-2147467259,
         "Source":"System",
         "WatsonBuckets":null
      },
      "HelpURL":null,
      "StackTraceString":" at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\r\n at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)\r\n at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)\r\n at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)\r\n at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)",
      "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
      "RemoteStackIndex":0,
      "ExceptionMethod":"8\nRead\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream\nInt32 Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)",
      "HResult":-2146232800,
      "Source":"System",
      "WatsonBuckets":null
   },
   "HelpURL":null,
   "StackTraceString":" at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n at ASP._Page_Views_home_Test_cshtml.Execute() in c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\foobarweb_dev\\Views\\Home\\Test.cshtml:line 14",
   "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
   "RemoteStackIndex":0,
   "ExceptionMethod":"8\nGetResponse\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.HttpWebRequest\nSystem.Net.WebResponse GetResponse()",
   "HResult":-2146233079,
   "Source":"System",
   "WatsonBuckets":null
}
```

I've read suggestion to edit the following settings, and I have tinkered with them all, but no matter what combination I use, I still get the above error:

```
http.KeepAlive
http.ProtocolVersion
http.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit
http.Timeout
```

If I try this in another project on my local computer, connecting to the "https" version of the site works. It is ***only*** when connecting from within the site over SSL.

I am stumped, and I'm not even sure if this is a code issue, a server issue, or maybe even a proxy/firewall issue.

Answer (score 4):

Check the TLS version of the host "https://www.foo-bar.com" and the .NET TLS version of your project. They should be equal.

Check by "Immediate window":

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

Answer (score 2):

The issue is something with the SSL -- probably a certificate issue of some sort. If it is public facing I would start by running [SSL Labs Analyizer](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) at it to see if that helps sniff out the cert problem.

Comment: Yeah, this was my first guess, but I'm not sure how to pinpoint the problem. I ran the SSL Labs Analyzer, but nothing really got back as problematic :/ http://i.imgur.com/CGUJVrj.png

Comment: That looks generally right. Two more things to try -- one would be to disable ssl verification and see if that fixes it. Another would be to try and get wireshark on the client and see what happens when the request fires off -- the devil is somewhere in the details.

Comment: This lead me to the correct solution! I still have TLS1.0 enabled on my server (according to SSL LAbs Analyzer), but the server I talk to had not. So I had to set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and resolved it by adding the following to my Powershell script:

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

Comment: +1 
combined the first two lines of this into one and solved my jira connection issue after the latest update. Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had this on a .NET Framework 4.0 app and the solution for us was as found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls). Create the following four DWORD keys and set them all to a value of 1 to enable strong cryptography and have the OS manage which version to use:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SystemDefaultTlsVersions
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SystemDefaultTlsVersions
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SchUseStrongCrypto
```